# Normalised Differences

Tags: t-test, normalization, group-differences

I have a dataset where my main variable is smoking. I have three definitions of smoking based on different questions and there are overlaps. By the first definition I have 100 people who are smokers, by the second definition there are 102 people (2 extra) and by the third one there are 110. I want to test if the group of smokers is different using normalised differences. Is this possible?

I am trying to use the normalised differences by Imbens and Wooldridge here: https://www.nber.org/sites/default/files/2021-03/lect_1_match_fig.pdf